# NGINX as reverse proxy - forwarding not working

Tags: https, nginx-reverse-proxy, forwarding

I've the following:

- HTTPS access to a NAS or something like that.
- NGINX as reserve proxy as container
- Container with a Tomcat as appcontainer.

NAS forwards HTTPS request as HTTP to NGINX container. Then NGINX container forwards HTTP request to my appcontainer.

I can access to my appcontainer login page but after login a POST is made as follows
Nginx access.log

```
POST /foo/login.do HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://nas.dns.server/foo/login.do
```

In *localhost_access.log* in appcontainer tomcat shows

```
POST /foo/doLogin.do HTTP/1.0" 302
```

And request as HTTP to the NAS

It seems that is ignoring X-Forwarded-Proto header.

My nginx.conf is configured as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name $hostname;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    error_log   /dev/stdout info;
    access_log  /dev/stdout;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    send_timeout 300;

    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;

    sendfile on;

    location /foo {
        proxy_set_header Origin "";
        set $appcontainer          http://appcontainer:8080;
        proxy_pass         $appcontainer;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $https;  #I’ve also tested with $scheme
    } 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having a look to the Developer Tool of Chrome in the Network tab in can see that for the call of `login.do` there is `Request URL: https://entry.proxy.url/foo/doLogin.do` but in the `Response Headers` I can see what is generating the problem `Location: http://proxy.entry.url/foo/login.do` that must be `Location: https://proxy.entry.url/foo/login.do` .

I've tried doing redirection as `proxy_redirect http://entry.proxy.url/ https://csprocure.ciport.be/;` in the location and it works.

So location is set as:

```
location /foo {
    proxy_set_header Origin "";
    set $appcontainer          http://appcontainer:8080;
    proxy_redirect     http://proxy.entry.url/ https://proxy.entry.url/;
    proxy_pass         $appcontainer;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $https;  #I’ve also tested with $scheme
}
```